# How to not select last sibling

Tags: jquery

How to not select last sibling

```
$(this).parent().siblings();
```

Above code selects all the siblings. But i don't want last sibling to be selected.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not(":last-child");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKfZp/).

Comment: Worth pointing out that this isn't supported in IE versions 8 and under

Comment: @Dave How come? You mixed up CSS pseudo class and JQuery selector.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(this).parent().siblings(":not(:last)");
```

or

```
$(this).parent().siblings().not(":last-child");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('parent childrens').not(':last')
```

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ajovan/edit#javascript,html,live)*

---

```
$('parent childrens').slice(0,-1)
```

#### *[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/ajovan/2/edit)*